# routes.maproute

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a problem, this is my first time to use the routes.maproute and i have a problems with a logical

i have this code:

```
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    //Ruta por defecto   --> pa' pruebas
    );



    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Registro",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{box}/{reg}"
      //defaults: new { controller = "Repositorio", action = "Registro" }
      //localhost:27105/Home/FichaRegistros/29200604-BCF7-4534-8DE9-00049D41A3E0-->FichaRegistros   -->Repositorio/Registro + id OBLIGATORIA
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Repositorio",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{box}"
      //defaults: new { controller = "Repositorio", action = "Repositorio", }
      //localhost:27105/User/Repositorio/378CE0F6-440A-4C63-BF08-08F760B4840B --> Repositorio  -->Repositorio/Repositorio + id OBLIGATORIA
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IsNotLogged",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "IsNotLogged", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //localhost:27105/Home/Index   -->   Home/Index -->Repositorio/IsNotLogged
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IsLogged",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "IsLogged", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //localhost:27105/User/Index  -->  User/Index  -->Repositorio/IsLogged
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Localhost",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/",
      defaults: new { controller = "Repositorio", action = "LocalHost" }
      //localhost:27105/   -->User/Login   -->Repositorio/LocalHost
    );
}
```

but i can't make works correctly

every MapRoute  have 4 items:
name (identificative to maproute)
url (the url to check at MapRoute)
defaults (only if is necesary)
Comments to look i want in this maproute (but this not work as i want)

can help me?

the error is that I do not get to go to the routes I want because I do not see the logic to put well comprovaciones path like url: "{controller} / {action} / {id}", so they go where i want (that is indicated in the commentary of each MapRoute

for example on the route: Registration 
I want that when the user enters a path such as: // localhost: 27105 / Home / FichaRegistros / 29200604-BCF7-4534-8DE9-00049D41A3E0

this redirect me to FichaRegistros
located in the controller Repositoro
action Repositorio
and having an id REQUIRED

(NOTE: I USE THE DEFAULT ROUTE FIRST ONLY TO TRY, TOO SEE URLS, I KNOW THAT THEN I HAVE PUT AT THE END)

Comment: Please tell us what error you have

Comment: Can you add to your question what result you expect and what kind of error you get?

Comment: _the error is that I do not get to go to the routes I want because I do not see the logic to put well comprovaciones path like url: "{controller} / {action} / {id}", so they go where i want (that is indicated in the commentary of each MapRoute_

*for example on the route: Registration
I want that when the user enters a path such as: // localhost: 27105 / Home / FichaRegistros / 29200604-BCF7-4534-8DE9-00049D41A3E0
this redirect me to FichaRegistros*

located in the controller Repositoro 
action Repositorio  
and having an id REQUIRED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution:

in routes.MapRoute, we configured as url:
url: "/ home / FichaRegistros /"
because we want to "capture" when the url points well.

then we define how we want it acts:
defaults: new {controller = "Records" action = "Index"}

There are indicating that we want to go to the controller record to action INDEX

that way we can capture cualquer route we need and send it to the controller and action that we want:

in the same way if the URL indicated:
url: "{controller} / {action} /"

we are indicating that we want to grab any controller and any action, that is to say:
if the url is: localhost: 45663 / CCCC / YYYY / XXXX
the routes.MapRoute, interpret the CCC as a controller and anger to look for our program,
in the same way that interara seek action within the controller AAA CCC
and the take as parameters XXX

devemos look at the order in which we place these "filters" because if for example we put a filter:
url: "/ home / Cars /"
and then add a filter for
url: "/ home / Cars / FichaRegistros /"

Never reach the page FICHAREGISTROS since 1 passes through the filter start / cars and how you can go through there, it captures and sige no longer looking if any more concrete for, as if, just look for the condition is met, without noticing if any more detailed

as to the variables listed in {}
for example:
url: "{controller} / {action} /"
Here we access to a controller either, and an action anyone as internamenta is saved in the variable {controller} the driver name i in the variable {action} the name of the action and then uses them to locate the driver and the corresponding action in our program

We can also add their own variables as podira be the case:
url: "{controller} / {action} / {ID}"

in this case, we have created the variable or parameter ID, you can use it in the controller action to which we would take this routes.MapRoute, BEARING IN MIND THAT THE ACTION WITHIN THE VARIABLE TO THIS HAVE TO CALL LIKE WE HAVE INDICATED HERE

They could also be variables that are not always required, so that whether there is or not any, between the same condition, indicate:
defaults: new {action = "IsNotLogged" id = UrlParameter.Optional}

in this way, we are indicating that the ID parameter that we have created, is optional, if not indicaramos the solo part entraria UrlParameter.Optional in this condition when a go and if there is not, would jump to the next check

sorry for delay in answering, but hey thought that if not davais with a solution to my question and if ... else I not indicate what the problem he had and as I have solved

Comment: both question and answer are useless